# cryptic expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

What's the sense of:

```
if ( /red|green|blue/.test(key) .. )
```

I have never seen that before, how does it work?

found on:
http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138135/Widget-factory

Comment: Do you mean beyond it being a simple regular expression? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply said, it tests the string `key` if it contains either `red`, `green` or `blue`.

this thing is, the stuff between the `//` is one way to create a [regexp object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp). the [.test()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp) operates on regexp objects and return true if finds a match or false if not.

a more spread out version is this:

```
key = "red orange yellow green";  //sample string

pattern = /red|green|blue/;
result = pattern.test(key);

if(result){.... //will execute since string contained red OR green
```

or

```
key = "red orange yellow green";  //sample string

pattern = new RegExp('red|green|blue');
result = pattern.test(key);

if(result){.... //will execute since string contained red OR green
```

Answer (score 1):

The `/red|green|blue/` part is a [**Regular Expression**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), and the [**`test()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method is used to search for a match between that regular expression and the string passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The slashes `/` denote a regex literal. The key variable is tested to match this expression. The *if block* will be executed if the string representation of key contains either `red`, `green` or `blue`.